# Use code on one device and show 'result' with others using push notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, xamarin.forms

I am using HTML Agility pack in Xamarin forms to scrape data from a website. When a condition returns true, I want to send a push notification to all users. However, this data is changing a lot and I think it would cost a lot of internet data and maybe battery, if the device with this app is constantly collecting the data in the background to check a certain condition.

This is a piece of the code to give you an idea:

```
var url = "https://www.goal.com/en-us/live-scores";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

var voetbalWedstrijdenHTML = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        .Equals("main-content")).ToList();
```

So I thought it might be a good idea to let only one device use this code and check if the condition is true and then only send the push notification to all users. I've made this image to give you a better idea about what I mean.

[image: notifications]

I thought it might be a good idea to use firebase messaging to send push notifications to all users, but how or what do I use to have only one device checking the C#? Should I use a website with the C# code that is running 24/7 (is this possible?), or something else? So... how do I run C# code 24/7?

EDIT:

I found out about 'Firebase functions'. Would this work for me? I'd have to change to javascript so I rather stick to C#.

Comment: Write a service that runs on your server every x minutes and sends notifications to the app.

Comment: Yes, but what kind of service do I use for this?

Comment: if running on your own server works for you, I would setup RabbitMQ or a similar message bus to send out notifications on. https://www.rabbitmq.com/  That's just a server with many languages supported as clients including .NET other message bus in .NET include https://masstransit-project.com/ and others

Comment: Look at [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) + firebase messaging. This is a solution that I've implemented

Comment: How about using AspNet Core [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ?

Comment: @Larry SignalR won't work when application closed

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I understand now how firebase messaging can be a good solution for offline clients. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Yes,you can use Firebase functions, there is .NET SDK https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/cloudfunctions/v1

Comment: @RomanMarusyk isn't that url for Google Cloud Functions only? Why is there actually a "Google cloud functions" (which costs money) and a "Firebase functions", which are both owned by google? I will take a look at hosted services, thank you.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk how does hosted services actually work and what does it do? I don't really get it from the documentation. Do you maybe have a small example?

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn Hosted service is a simple console application that can qeued background tasks that run sequentially and runs task on a timer or continuously(24/7). It doesn't have any interface. This service can checks a certain condition and send push notification using firebase(FCM).  Then you can deploy it to azure as a Docker Container Instances  and pay ~0,54 $ per day (Or deploy it to any other cloud or hosting) . If you are interested in this way then I can describe it with more details and steps with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how i would have done it

1. Create an Azure web job that checks the condition. You can schedule it to run according to your requirements.
2. Create an Azure notification hub (ANH) and link it to Firebase and equivalent in IOS and other platforms as per requirements.
3. Create a web api that every app user will call. In this api call, register every device with Azure notification hub. The registrations can include tags to which you can send notifications to.
4. When the web job needs to trigger a notification, it will call the ANH directly or through the web api and send a broadcast notification. You can also narrow down the users to send notifications based on tags.

One advantage of using ANH is that you don't need to worry about sending to multiple platforms. You just send to tags it will go corresponding users of all platforms.

I believe that this document may help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/notification-hubs/. Hope I have helped.

EDIT:

Would you be using 2 projects: Yes you would be using atleast 2 projects. One for web api and 1 for each platform that you want your app to be in.

Point in Using Azure Notifications: It comes with great deal of features that will make your life easier especially if your application runs on multiple platforms. However, you can use FCM directly. Actually ANH will also use FCM behind the doors.

Putting the code you want to run every some time in `Startup.cs`: Thats a bad idea. You should ideally be using a web job for that. Startup code is executed only once in lifetime of application. You don't want your notification trigger code to be in Startup class. However if using webjob is not something you want, you can be using the cron scheduler.

EDIT 2:

You can use the timer in `Startup.cs` however, i would not recommend that. One class should ideally have only one purpose and business logic is not for Startup. You should consider moving out the method to another class.

If you decide to use webjobs, you would create different projects for web job. These offerings like ANH, web job etc exist for one reason - to make your life easier. You can always do everything on your own if you are ready to work extra mile. 
PS web job is becoming obsolete and people are now moving to Azure functions.

Comment: So if I'm right, I will be using two different visual studio projects? One Xamarin forms for the android app, and one ASP.NET Core Web Application? And then I run my condition check code in the web application project and I use the xamarin forms project to receive notifications coming from firebase cloud messaging, which is coming from the code from the web application?

Comment: Next question: what is the point of using azure notifications? Why can't I directly send a notification with FCM?

Comment: Third question (sorry if I ask too much in the comments): I am testing this code in an ASPNET project in `Startup.cs` https://pastebin.com/SqgweSLP (too long to paste here). My question is, if I publish this, will it run 24/7 or wil it only run when I load the page? When I reload the page (https://sportsalertaspnet.azurewebsites.net/) it is updated, but I don't know if it is updating while I am not looking at it. This would be important for the notifications.

Comment: I think I got it! In the ASP.NET in `startup.cs` I've put the HTML Agility pack and FCM sending notification code. In the xamarin project I subrcribed to topical "all" which I will use to send the notification to. Now my code is running even when I am not using the actual website, and it is checking the conditions instead that my app is doing that :)

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn Sorry, I couldn't check SO for past few days. I have updated my answer. Let me know if that answers all your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. As you said, startup code is only executed once in lifetime, but what is actually the problem about that? I have a timer in my code so the code executes every second, so what would be the benefit of a WebJob? Do I have to create a new project for each WebJob? And next to that, before I set up the ANH: what would for example be a big advantage when using it, as FCM is also cross-platform?